# Telerik RadHtmlGraph Label for Date Formatted Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

This is my RadHtmlChart Code

```
   <telerik:RadHtmlChart 
        ID="RadHtmlChart2"
        Width="900"
        runat="server">
        <PlotArea>
            <Series>
                <telerik:ColumnSeries DataFieldY="Value" Stacked="false">
                    <LabelsAppearance DataField="Key" Position="InsideBase" />
                </telerik:ColumnSeries>
            </Series>
        </PlotArea>
    </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
```

and this is from code behind

```
    Dictionary<string, decimal> result = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

    result["Jul 2013"] = 209.83m;
    result["Aug 2013"] = 152m;


    RadHtmlChart2.DataSource = result;
```

The problem on the result is the label will auto format to LongDate string. I've tried to format it in LabelsAppearance but its not working..

```
<LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="{0:MMMM}" DataField="Key" Position="InsideBase" />
```

Result:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ClientTemplate: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-client-templates-for-tooltips-and-labels.html. Also, try a class or data table for the data source, I am not sure if dictionaries are supported at all.